# HTML5/CSS Page displays correct in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to fix up my webpage for this [site](http://www.bondsolutionsnj.com) and if you were to visit you would see that in Firefox it does not display the header bar correctly but in Chrome it does. I do not understand why. My research shows that if Firefox finds an error on the page it screws up loading and displaying the rest of it. However, I can't seem to find an error anywhere. Thanks for any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Bond Solutions | Home</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #000;
}
#footer {
    width: 75%;
}
#copyright img {
    width: auto\9;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#copyright {
    color: #FFF;
    float: left;
}
#header {
    width: 75%;
    height: 84px;
}
#header h3 {
position: absolute;
top: 4%;
left: 15%;
}
#header a {
    color: black;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var video;
window.onload = function () {
window.video = document.getElementById("video");
window.video.addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
window.video.volume=0.5;
}
function myHandler() {
        window.video.currentTime = 7;
        window.video.volume=0;
        window.video.play();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<div id="header">
<svg>

<defs>
<linearGradient id="menugrad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
<stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(94,94,94);stop-opacity:1" />
<stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(137,137,137);stop-opacity:1" />
</linearGradient>
</defs>

<rect width="100%" height="84" x="0" y="0" style="fill:url(#menugrad);" />
</svg>
<h3><a href="http://www.bondsolutionsnj.com">Home |</a><a href="http://www.bondsolutionsnj.com/graphicdesign.html"> Graphic Design |</a><a href="http://www.bondsolutionsnj.com/webdesign.html"> Web Design |</a><a href="http://www.bondsolutionsnj.com/marketing.html"> Marketing |</a> <a href="http://www.bondsolutionsnj.com/computercasemods.html"> Computer Case Mods |</a> <a href="http://www.bondsolutionsnj.com/computerbuilds.html"> Computer Builds |</a> <a href="http://www.bondsolutionsnj.com/socialnetworks.html"> Social Networks |</a> <a href="http://www.bondsolutionsnj.com/contact.html"> Contact</a></h3>
</div>
</center>
<center>
<div id="content">
<video controls="controls" id="video" autoplay="true" width="50%" height="50%" onEnded="restart()">
<source src="Intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="Intro.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
</div>
</center>
<center>
<div id="footer">
<hr />
<div id="copyright">
<a href="http://www.fatcow.com/green-certified/bondsolutionsnj.com" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('http://www.fatcow.com/green-certified/bondsolutionsnj.com','greenCertified','toolb ar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=550,height=700,left=50,top=50'); return false;"><img src="http://www.fatcow.com/green-certified/hosting-badge-2.png" border="0" /></a>Copyright: <strong>©</strong> Bond Solutions LLC
</div>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, what is the error? In what way is the "header bar" incorrectly displayed?

Comment: There is no error but when one visits the page, in Firefox, the header bar at the top is shrunken to a very small size. Would you like me to link a picture?

Comment: Increase #header{width: 85% or greater;}

Comment: @Ani does it have to be 80% or greater? And [here](http://i.imgur.com/MBEQt0P.png) is the screenshot

Comment: Also as the other answers show, using 100% for svg width also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#SVGElement) say that `width` should default to `100%`, but for whatever reason that doesn't seem to be the case in FireFox.

Try using

```
<svg width="100%">
```

Setting that with firebug makes it look correct to me in FireFox.  Note that this does not have the same effect as `style="width: 100%;"`

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/width?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=SVG/Attribute/width)'s says the same thing about the default width, so this may be a bug with Firefox

Comment: The spec you cite was actually self-contradictory about how width behaves there.  SVG 2 drafts clarified the self-contradictory bits and Firefox implements what the SVG2 spec says.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<svg style="width: 100%;">` instead of `<svg>`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to make the svg the same width as the header?

```
#header svg {
    width:100%;
}
```

But why not make it a `background-image` instead? Or use a gradient generator and do it with CSS?
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Thanks for that link I will have to check that out. Ya my understanding was that it would automatically default to 100%

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the css:

```
 #header{width: 85%;}
```